# Passing Queries as Regards To 3 Operands (Length + breadth * 2), Cannot calculate Perimeter in NASM

Tags: c++, nasm

So today i decided to play around with nasm again, i have been gathering some knowledge with it lately, hence i decided to give myself some projects before i can certify that i am 'OK' with it

I was trying to calculate the perimeter of a rectangle using NASM in c/c++ the code looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib,h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
    {
       int length;
       int breadth;
       int perimeter;

      printf("Enter The Length: \n");
      scanf("%d",&length);
      printf("Enter The Breadth: \n");
      scanf("%d",&breadth);

      perimeter = length + breadth * 2;
     printf("Perimeter is : %d",perimeter);

      return 0;
        system("PAUSE");

    }
```

Which Should work perfectly now i try doing the same in NASM , the part of Length + breadth * 2 gives some problems as it produces a rather outrageous answer other than the original thing source code looks like this

```
section  .data 

    msg:
    msg1: db 'A program to Calculate The Perimiter of A Rectangle',10,0
    msg2: db '******************************************************',10,0
    ;msg3: db ''Length + Breadth * 2 =  Perimeter'
    msg3: db 'Enter Length :',0
    msg4: db 'Enter Breadth :',0
    msg5: db 'Perimeter is = %d ',0
        formin : db '%d',0
    formout : db '%d',10,0
    num1 : times 4 db 0
    num2 : times 4 db 0

section  .text

    global _main
    extern _scanf
    extern _printf


_main :
    push ebp
    mov esp ,ebp
    push msg1
    call _printf

    push msg2
    call _printf

    push msg3
    call _printf

    mov eax, num1
    push num1
    push formin
    call _scanf

    push msg4
    call _printf

    mov eax, num2
    push num2
    push formin
    call _scanf


    mov eax,dword[num1]
    mov ebx,dword[num2]

    mov ecx,2
    ; Perimeter is always L + B *2

    add eax,ebx

    imul ecx

    push msg5
    call _printf

    ; destroy stack
    pop ebp
    mov esp, ebp

    ret
```

Notice the Perimeter area gives me issues , why is this so?

Comment: Write the program in C++.  Place the parts you want in assembly language into a separate function.  Compile the program.  Tell the compiler to print the assembly language.  Compare the assembly language to the stuff you wrote.

Comment: Before I can answer, what are the calling conventions, in assembly language, for `_printf`?